# How to turn quoted string input into value of a vector?

Tags: r, string

I would like to accept input from the user in a format such as:

```
arg_from_user = "c(1,2,3)"
```

and then assign the content of this string to a vector, such that:

```
vector = mystery_function(arg_from_user)

vector
[1] 1 2 3
```

What do I use in place of `mystery_function`?

Comment: May be `eval(parse(text="c(1,2,3)"))`

Comment: Just make sure that this isn't part of a web server interface or some such as you are allowing the users to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: Thanks, @BrodieG – good caveat

Comment: You should need this only under special and rare circumstances. Usually there is a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
eval(parse(text="c(1,2,3)"))
```